# Replace all links from the text that don't contain query string (PHP)

Tags: php, regex, string

I want to replace (well, alter) all youtube links from the text block that don't have query string with manual query string.

For example, text code could look like this:

```
http://youtube.com/embed/ABC
http://youtube.com/embed/DEF?foo=bar
http://youtube.com/embed/EFG
```

And I want it to look like:

```
http://youtube.com/embed/ABC?sup=bro
http://youtube.com/embed/DEF?foo=bar
http://youtube.com/embed/EFG?sup=bro
```

What is the best way of achieving that using PHP?

Comment: How do you want to alter it?

Comment: Exactly as stated in the example - I want to add query string manually (but only for those that don't have it), sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Is the `sup` part constant? How is it determined?

Comment: Yup, that's a constant.

Comment: Okay. I've posted [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20074407/1438393) below. See if that helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Simply check if :

- there's no `?`, with `^([^?]+)$`
- the query string is empty, with `\?$`

```php
$links = array(
    'http://youtube.com/embed/ABC',
    'http://youtube.com/embed/DEF?foo=bar',
    'http://youtube.com/embed/EFG',
    'http://youtube.com/embed/HIJ?',
);

$nlinks = preg_replace('/^([^?]+)$|\?$/', '$1?sup=bro', $links);

var_dump($nlinks);
/*
* array(3) { 
*     [0]=> string(36) "http://youtube.com/embed/ABC?sup=bro" 
*     [1]=> string(36) "http://youtube.com/embed/DEF?foo=bar" 
*     [2]=> string(36) "http://youtube.com/embed/EFG?sup=bro" 
*     [2]=> string(36) "http://youtube.com/embed/HIJ?sup=bro" 
* }
*/
```

**EDIT**
I added a case for urls with empty query string, like `http://youtube.com/embed/HIJ?`

Answer (score 1):

A solution without regex. Get all the URLs into an array, use [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/parse_url) to grab the query string part (if there exists one) and append the custom `$query` inside the loop.

```
$query = 'sup=bro'; // define this

foreach($urls as &$url) {
    $parts = parse_url($url);
    if (!isset($parts['query'])) {
        $url .= '?' . $query;
    }
}

print_r($urls);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => http://youtube.com/embed/ABC?sup=bro
    [1] => http://youtube.com/embed/DEF?foo=bar
    [2] => http://youtube.com/embed/EFG?sup=bro
)
```

[**Demo.**](https://eval.in/69824)

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need check strings using **preg_match**. If you have remainder after "?", leave it as is; otherwise, add "sup=bro".

Comment: When you want to perform a replacement, it is, in general, useless to use the `preg_match()` function before since the `preg_replace()` function performs the replacement if and only if a pattern match is found.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this pattern:

```
$urls = <<<LOD
http://youtube.com/embed/ABC
http://youtube.com/embed/DEF?foo=bar
http://youtube.com/embed/EFG
LOD;

$urls = preg_replace('~/[^/?\s]*\K$~m', '?sup=bro', $urls);
```